# JQuery Code to adress only one DIV Row - Equal Height Colums DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is my [JQuery Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/kWB99/4/)

This JQuery Code speaks to all `".container"` DIV's and makes an equal height in each row when i edit text in one row.

i need it in the one row only (the other rows doesn't need this space in the box) i need this `"growing up"` in this row how i edit more text - not in the other ones

different `div-classes`, flexbox and table are not a solution for my work - i need a supplement to my `JQuery` Code

**Here is my JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.box').each(function() {  
        var highestBox1 = 0;
        $('.container').each(function(){
            if($(this).height() > highestBox1) 
               highestBox1 = $(this).height(); 
        }).height(highestBox1);  
   });    
});
```

thanks !

Comment: [Is this what you mean?](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/kWB99/10/)

Comment: YES IT IS ! but why this doesn't work on IE 8 ? any solution ?

Comment: Not sure, I don't have IE8 to test, are there any errors?

Comment: not that i know of but my JQuery animation (with my hover-effect) doens't work ...

@Tilwin Joy has a solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, You need equalize the height of first `.container` alone in each `.box`. Then you can do this:

```
var height=0;
var elms = $(".container").filter(function(){
  var $siblings = $(this).parent().find(".container");
  var index = $(this).index($siblings);
  if(index==0){
    height = ($(this).height() > height)?$(this).height():height;
    return true;
  }
  else return false;
});
elms.height(height)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/kWB99/6/)

**Update** (*as per comments)*

```
var heights=[];
$(".container").each(function(){
 var $siblings = $(this).parent().find(".container");
 var index = $siblings.index($(this));
if(!heights[index])
    heights[index]= $(this).height();
else
    heights[index] = ($(this).height() > heights[index])? $(this).height():heights[index];
});

$(".container").each(function(){
  var $siblings = $(this).parent().find(".container");
  var index = $siblings.index($(this));
  $(this).height(heights[index]);
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/kWB99/11/)

Comment: not the first alone - the other ones too but not with the same height of the first. i would like to have a equal height like in tables - each row on the same line but with an equal height

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you identify the one specific container div that you want this to work with, but if you don't have any other informatin (other classes, etc.) as you seem to be saying in your question, you can fall back on its position: Which `.container` element is it on the page?

```
$('.container:eq(0)')
// or
$('.container').eq(0)
```

...will select the first one, or of course you can use larger indexes (1, 2, 3) to select other ones.

So for instance:

```
    var containers = $('.container');
    containers.each(function(){

        if($(this).height() > highestBox1) 
           highestBox1 = $(this).height(); 
    });
    containers.eq(4).height(highestBox1);
```

...will set only the fifth container to the height determined by the loop.

Comment: when i put your code in my example it doesn't work.
and another point: my database edit the text - i can't say which row wraps in another line –

Comment: @mlemtes: I have no idea what you're asking, then. *"my database edit the text"* Your database can't edit the text in the browser, that sentence doesn't make any sense. If you can edit your question to make it clear what the problem is and what your goal is, someone can probalby help you. But that isn't clear at present.

Comment: with your code i adress this one container which i have adress in my JQuery (with eq(4) - and its doesn't work in my example at present). And my Problem: my Divs become filled automatically (PHP) - so i don't know how long the divs are / or how many textlines are in there